# Sliding divs cause webpage to extend beyond my footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my problem, follow the steps below as not sure how to explain this without seeing it happen:

https://www.facebook.com/TheBackyrdCricketr/app_203351739677351

1) Click on the "About Us" button" - A section should slide down

2) Click on the "Rules" button (the top left image of the group of 9) - another section should slide down

3) Click on the red "Twenty20" button (the left of the 3 emblem options) - another section should slide down.

4) Minimise all the sections by clicking all the buttons in the reverse order from above i.e.(Twenty20 then, rules then about us)

5) Scroll to the bottom of the page where you will find a large blank section below my footer which hasn't slid back up to the bottom of my footer.

How do I fix this so that this empty space/height of my webpage is always the height of the bottom of my footer even when different divs are sliding down/up?

Comment: please provide a screenshot and/or fiddle

Comment: sadly i cant because I don't have enough rep points to post photos or multiple links :/

If you follow my steps above you will see what I'm talking about

Comment: You don't need points to post a fiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry, I won't use any fb apps I don't know

Answer (score 0):

No one will open the FB through your link, so you need to understand that it's a matter of security.

According to heading of your post I think you need this:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/create-a-floating-div-which-will-come-up-and-down-automatica/